# Show root of scipy dendrogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I've produced a dendrogram in `scipy` that looks like this:[image: leximin method dendrogram]

I'd like to draw the 'root' of the dendrogram—a little tick in the middle, going  from where the two largest clusters merge up to `z=0`. How can I draw this effectively?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy as hclust

Z = array([[ 22.      ,  23.      ,   0.71094 ,   2.      ],
   [  0.      ,   1.      ,   1.62068 ,   2.      ],
   [  2.      ,  33.      ,   1.62068 ,   3.      ],
   [  3.      ,  34.      ,   1.62068 ,   4.      ],
   [  4.      ,   5.      ,   1.62068 ,   2.      ],
   [  6.      ,  36.      ,   1.62068 ,   3.      ],
   [  7.      ,  37.      ,   1.62068 ,   4.      ],
   [  8.      ,   9.      ,   1.62068 ,   2.      ],
   [ 10.      ,  39.      ,   1.62068 ,   3.      ],
   [ 11.      ,  40.      ,   1.62068 ,   4.      ],
   [ 12.      ,  13.      ,   1.62068 ,   2.      ],
   [ 14.      ,  42.      ,   1.62068 ,   3.      ],
   [ 15.      ,  43.      ,   1.62068 ,   4.      ],
   [ 16.      ,  17.      ,   1.62068 ,   2.      ],
   [ 18.      ,  45.      ,   1.62068 ,   3.      ],
   [ 19.      ,  46.      ,   1.62068 ,   4.      ],
   [ 20.      ,  21.      ,   1.62068 ,   2.      ],
   [ 32.      ,  48.      ,   1.62068 ,   4.      ],
   [ 24.      ,  25.      ,   1.62068 ,   2.      ],
   [ 26.      ,  50.      ,   1.62068 ,   3.      ],
   [ 27.      ,  51.      ,   1.62068 ,   4.      ],
   [ 28.      ,  29.      ,   1.62068 ,   2.      ],
   [ 30.      ,  53.      ,   1.62068 ,   3.      ],
   [ 31.      ,  54.      ,   1.62068 ,   4.      ],
   [ 35.      ,  41.      ,   5.53516 ,   8.      ],
   [ 47.      ,  52.      ,   5.53516 ,   8.      ],
   [ 56.      ,  38.      ,   5.62891 ,  12.      ],
   [ 55.      ,  57.      ,   5.62891 ,  12.      ],
   [ 44.      ,  58.      ,   5.64453 ,  16.      ],
   [ 49.      ,  59.      ,   5.64453 ,  16.      ],
   [ 60.      ,  61.      ,   6.238281,  32.      ]])

hclust.dendrogram(Z)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get everything you need from `dendrogram`'s return value.

`icoord` and `dcoord` contain the coordinates of each link drawn. You can calculate the center point of the last link's horizontal connection and draw a short line from there.

```
ret = hclust.dendrogram(Z)

xk = ret['icoord'][-1]
yk = ret['dcoord'][-1]

x = np.mean(xk[1:3])
y1 = yk[1]
y2 = 7  # y-coordinate of endpoint

plt.plot([x, x], [y1, y2], color=ret['color_list'][-1])
```

[image: dendrogram with root]